# error in configure mod_wsgi with Apache2.2

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am follow this http://pradyumnajoshi.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/setting-up-mod_wsgi-for-apache-and-django-on-windows/

I am using python2.6, Apache2.2, Django1.3 and mod_wsgi>3 on windows xp. now I have installed Apache correctly it is running well. and I have add the following line in httpd.conf file:-
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
Now i restart my Apache server It's running well. But when I have add the following lines in httpd.conf:-

```
WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi “C:/wsgi_app/wsgi_handler.py”

<Directory “C:/wsgi_app”>
  AllowOverride None
  Options None
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then restart my Apache server it give error on the prompt "The request operation has failed"

please help me I am new in python.

Thank You.

Comment: I deleted my answer.  I edited your question with proper code tags and your httpd.conf looks correct.  Look in the apache log file (the error.log file) and/or in the Windows event viewer to see what error apache is throwing.  Please edit your question with that error message.

Comment: You may have some luck with the official mod_wsgi documentation at http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationInstructions

Comment: You also might have much better luck on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Whenever debugging Apache, the first place to check is the error and access logs. I've never used apache with Windows, but if you find logs, you'll get a much more descriptive error message.

FYI, I believe it is normally recommended to make the wsgi_handler use a .wsgi extension (though I think this is probably because it is normally named django).

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have wsgi_handler.py file in the directory C:/wsgi_app.
problem may be the symbol with which you are quoting.
replace “C:/wsgi_app/wsgi_handler.py” with "C:/wsgi_app/wsgi_handler.py" and “C:/wsgi_app” with "C:/wsgi_app".